# Add widget event handler from Designer in MonoDevelop Gtk#

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I created a new GTK# project in MonoDevelop. I added a button from Designer, and now I want to handle its clicked event. Can I do it from Designer, or do I have to do it from code using

```
button1.Clicked += ClickHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/building-a-simple-application-using-the-stetic-gui-designer/. You have to go open Properties->Signals, and then double click the event to create a default handler that throws a `NotImplementedException`.

[image]